# Reformat file cut of variable in pycharm

Tags: python-3.x, macos, pycharm

I am using pycharm for my application development. However, whenever I want to reformat the file, pycharm slip the long expression into two line in the middle of variable. Anyone know what setting I should set it up to prevent it?

Pycharm version: pycharm 2019.3
Os: osx Catalina

```
s = xxxxxxyyyyxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
#=>
s = xxxxxxyyyyxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxx
```

Answer (score 0):

This should help you: File -> Settings -> Search for 'hard wrap'

You can edit the setting by clicking on it (it may look disabled for edit, but trust me it's not):

[image]

Comment: i have setting for hard wrap  `120` under "code stype" => "python" and doing some search that i am not able to disable it. so i do not think that is answer